How to handle multiple concurrent live plots in Pyqt6 efficiently?
I have been writing a GUI program using PyQt6 that basically communicates with certain laboratory instruments for N number of steps and concurrently plots the data and related derivatives on a GUI that updates separately. As of now, I have created a QRunnable to perform the data acquisition (a sort of a scan) and and another QRunnable to concurrently update the plots sequentially say every 0.1s. I have around 5 plots as the number of data points increases to around 5000 sometimes it freezes. I thought it was because of limited specifications of my CPU/RAM but upon checking Task Manager, my usage is pretty low.
How can I improve this and make it more efficient to concurrently acquire data and update the plots at the same time? Is there any way I can use multiple CPU cores, or another form of Multithreading to make this more efficient?

how are you drawing stuff ? you need a [mcve] , in any case, since python only allows one thread to execute code, the usual answer is "don't draw that much" , users can't really tell the difference between a hundred points and a thousand points, you can use any decimation algorithm to limit the amount of drawing you need to do.

The only way to use multiple CPU cores is by using multiprocessing, but that will only help any actual CPU bound computation. You need to understand where the freeze occurs: if it is caused by the communication with the instruments and/or the computation of its data, then it may be worth it considering multiprocessing. If it's an issue in rendering (eg: too many points to update) then you need to see if you can optimize it (as suggested above by Ahmed). Note that it seems odd that you actually "update the plots" from a QRunnable: the UI must never be directly accessed from external threads.
